# When working in agile, how should my work habits change?

Tags: agile

I am working in a dev team where we religiously follow agile.

However, I have not had to change how I work (unit testing etc doesn't count as I do that anyway). I mean, do I need to change how or how often I communicate? This soft skill side of things with agile is what I am interested in.

Thanks

Comment: If you feel you communicate too rearely, communicate more often. Otherwise you're doing ok. Seriously, how can we know how much you communicate in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your team is utilizing agile well, then you probably should see some changes in how you work. It's possible that you already developed with a fairly "agile-compatible" mindset, even if your previous work experience was in a more waterfall-style methodology.

Some specific things that I think agile developers ought to be doing (and in a well-run agile team, will naturally find they **need** to do)

- **Focus on incremental, complete changes rather than massive architectures** - This is a core tenant of agile from the macro planning side, but it's also important to practice even for an individual developer. With a 2 or 3 week iteration, you'll find you simply don't have the time to spend 1 1/2 weeks developing something, and half a week integrating it all together.
- **Check in early, check in often, and check in working code** - Don't do this, and you'll soon find you're *that guy* famous for breaking the build with a day left before the iteration ends.
- **Know what's blocking you, and what is likely to block you in the upcoming week or two, and tell people about it** - No one in an agile team likes hearing at the last second that a developer working on a critical piece is held up waiting for something to complete his work.
- **Think about the end of an iteration throughout the iteration** - Every line of code you write should be done with the consideration of whether this is realistic to complete before the iteration is over.
- **Always Be Crunching** (hey, I couldn't have a pithy list of advice without a cute, Glengarry Glen Ross ripped off acronym!) You'll learn by your second or third iteration that slacking off for a week followed by some all nighters is going to bite you in the ass.

If you're already following all these - great! They're certainly general best practices rather than being specific to Agile. I think most developers do have a bad habit or two that this list addresses, though (I know I do on occasion.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ryan's great points here are a couple more.

- **Discuss your ideas with other members of your team.** Your fellow developers will quickly point out potential flaws in your thinking and suggest alternatives (be ready to listen and not get offended). I found this works best during planning/story tasking. In a 2-3 week sprint it is painfully obvious when you go down the wrong path. It might even stop you from successfully finishing all you tasks/stories. If others know your plan of attack up front it makes it easier for them to step in and help you out finishing your work if you need it.
- **Do not hesitate to suggest new ways of doing things.** One of the great things about agile is that team *processes* are not set in stone but **evolve** from a series of retrospectives. If you have developers who never speak up, the process never changes and things do not get better.
- **Put your user's hat on.** Every application has an end user. Sometimes (especially when you do not have a close contact with your users) you have to step back and question decisions (even if made by a product owner). If you can make a good case, not only your users but the entire team will benefit from it since the product will be better received. Developers do not do this often enough. We want to make things better, faster and leaner in the expense of other, sometimes more important things like delivering on time or adding more features.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The specifics of agile will be different for every person you ask. Yes, you probably want to communicate regularly, but you don't want to take it to extremes that keep you (or your coworkers) from being productive.

But like I said, it will be different for everybody. The only people who know how best to match your team are the people on your team. Just tell them you aren't used to agile and you were wondering how you've been handling it. They're really the only ones who will be able to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer but was very useful to all developers that asked me that question:

There is a book called Practices of an agile developer,http://www.pragprog.com/titles/pad/practices-of-an-agile-developer.

This book will specifically answer to your question. I like it very much because it's not just about the process, but behaviors and psychology.

Answer (score 0):

Attitude-related things:

1) Good pair programming means **making an effort to explain things really well and listening carefully**. That's a skill in itself. You have to learn how other people tackle things and be patient when other people tackle things differently from you.

2) Being **prepared to be flexible and change your mind**. The smaller the ego, the easier and less painful it is to handle this.

3) To do agile well, **you need to be communicating continuously** with everybody in the wider team (i.e. not just devs - sysadmins, managers, customers, network admins, hardware people...) Part of this is feeling comfortable, safe and confident - i.e. there needs to be real trust in the team, not just phoney trust - real trust

4) Be **prepared to work outside your specialism and comfort zone**. I often have to pair with graphic designers, system admins and DBAs. Saying "that's not my job" isn't part of agile. We're part of a multidisciplinary team and getting the product released in a useful state is the whole team's problem - not just looking after my pet specialism.

5) Try to **keep things simple and minimal** - no "we'll make it totally generic" or "we'll need it later". Think ["you aren't gonna need it."](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html) We're shooting for small, simple, concrete steps  informed by feedback.

6) **Tackle the difficult things and the things that aren't clear first** - so that the you get feedback on the problems as early as possible so you if you have to revise estimates or cancel the work the customer gets informed as soon as possible.

7) Try to **keep the team dynamics co-operative rather than competitive**. Pitting people against each other pulls the team apart - and it gets you well-polished fragments and a broken product rather than a cohesive whole made by people that give-and-take as they find necessary to be successful.